# Gerund or Participle? Which one is correct?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

What do you think of these sentences? I found them on the Net. I mean, should they function here as a gerund or a participle? Are both of them possible?
1 Smoking cigarettes are dangerous
2 Smoking cigarettes is dangerous

Comment: I'd say that "smoking cigarettes" is a non-finite gerund-participial clause functioning as subject of the sentence. Non-finite clause subjects take singular agreement, so only 2. is correct.

Comment: Flying aeroplanes can be dangerous.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gerund and participle comparison](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/494665/gerund-and-participle-comparison)

Comment: @BillJ If the first one is correct (read warning about bush fires in Oz), the head is the noun *cigarettes* and *smoking* is an attributive modifier.

Comment: Yes, but discarded lit cigarettes are usually called "lighted (or burning) cigarettes", not "smoking cigarettes*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 is correct, as "smoking cigarettes" is a gerund phrase, acting as a noun/subject in the sentence. However, 1 can also be correct if what you mean is that cigarettes that are burning (having smoke coming out of them) are dangerous things. :)

Comment: I'd say that "smoking cigarettes" is a gerund-participial **clause**.